# Shutdown system by timeout during suspend

Tags: fedora, gnome, power-management, shutdown, suspend

Currently I have settings in GNOME Power Management to setup timeout after which my system will suspend.

I want to add an additional timeout for the system to shutdown after some period of inactivity during its suspend.

So it will looks like that:

1. Suspend after 15 minutes of inactivity.
2. Shutdown after 12 hours of inactivity during suspend.

Comment: I am new to Linux and if there is a way, I don't know. Sorry. But you can create a Python (or whatever) script to enter the proper command in the terminal. So it will automatically do what you want.

Comment: AFAIK Gnome uses `systemd` for the actual handling of all sleep states. If Gnome's own UI does not provide a setting for what you wish, you might need to setup a configuration at the `systemd` level. Would you be willing to? And in any case, what you want to achieve requires a hardware clock able (and enabled) to wake up the system from suspend. Does your system have a `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm` file?

Comment: @LL3 I'm fine with any non-UI methods. Yes, my system have `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm` file.

Answer (score 2):

If hibernation is fine, use systemd's `suspend-then-hibernate` which will hibernate a suspended system after a timeout.
In `sleep.conf` set `HibernateDelaySec=` to your desired value.

Source [official systemd manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sleep.conf.html).

---

EDIT:

For using hibernation, Fedora needs to be reconfigured in order to enable it.

1. First of all you'll need a swap partition **at least** the size of your RAM - hibernation means saving the contents of RAM to the swap partition and thus the size is self-explaining. Usually this would mean shrinking your current partition and creating a new swap partition.

Guides for this are around here:

- e.g. [shink partition via live boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2605/change-main-partition-size-to-install-another-distribution), then create swap partition e.g. via cfdisk
- or [this one via LVM management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62163/123460)

Do not forget to add the swap partition it in `/etc/fstab` and activate the usage via `swapon -a`. Example fstab-entry:

```
# swap:
UUID=abc123-this-is-a-uuid none swap sw 0 0
```

2. Add the resume option to the initramfs. Fedora uses `dracut` for this, and I'll follow [this guide](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/fedora-hibernate.html).

- create a file `/etc/dracut.conf.d/resume.conf` with the line `add_dracutmodules+=" resume "` (make sure not to forget the spaces)
- run `dracut -f`

3. Add the swap partition to grub, so it knows from where to resume:

- in `/etc/default/grub` search for the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=`
- add  `resume=UUID=abc123-this-is-a-uuid` (i.e. the swap UUID)
- [update grub](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152222/equivalent-of-update-grub-for-rhel-fedora-centos-systems): `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` or `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`

4. I don't think this is necessary, but can't hurt. Activate hibernation in `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf`:

   ```
   [Sleep]
   AllowHibernation=yes
   HibernateMode=shutdown
   ```
5. Reboot and test hibernation: open some windows, run `systemctl hibernate`. It should shut down and the windows resume after you reboot.

Comment: I don't think Fedora supports hibernation.  :( https://pagure.io/fedora-workstation/blob/master/f/hibernationstatus.md

Comment: @rickhg12hs not by default, but you may enable it. Prerequisite is a swap partition of at least the size of the RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Fedora uses `systemd` as the system's overall manager, and Gnome by default relays Sleep/Standby/Suspend operations to `systemd`.

Assuming that by "Suspend" we mean "Suspend-to-RAM" (as opposed to "-to-Disk") and that by "Shutdown" we mean literally "powering off the machine", and also assuming a machine fitted with a hardware clock that supports system wakeup and thus enabled in the BIOS/EFI as an accepted wakeup device, it is possible to configure `systemd` via some carefully crafted "Units" (as in `systemd` parlance) so as to implement a self-poweroff after some specified time spent in "Suspend" state, while also not involving hibernation (nor any dedicated swap/partitions) at all during the transitions.

These custom `systemd` Units essentially arm a wakeup `[Timer]` immediately before entering the "Suspend" state, and once the alarm triggers the system is woken up to execute the custom `[Service]` associated with the `[Timer]`. Such `[Service]` of course performs the power-off operation. Should the machine be woken up through some other means instead, hence the timer had not elapsed yet, the self-poweroff is not performed and gets cancelled altogether.

The `systemd` Units I have come up with to implement such logic are quite a few, so here is a shell script that installs all of them. The script needs to be run only once, as "root" (via `sudo` is ok), in order to set things up in the *system-wide* (not the user-wide) configuration of `systemd`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh --

sysd=/etc/systemd/system

set -e

mkdir -p "$sysd/systemd-suspend.service.d"

cat > "$sysd/systemd-suspend.service.d/99-trigger-system-back-after-suspend.conf" <<'EOF'
[Service]
ExecStopPost=-/bin/systemctl --no-block start system-is-back-after-suspend.target
EOF

cat > "$sysd/cancel-self-poweroff.service" <<'EOF'
[Unit]
Description=Cancel self-poweroff after suspend
After=system-is-back-after-suspend.target
Conflicts=self-poweroff.timer

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/rm -f /run/systemd/system/self-poweroff.timer

[Install]
WantedBy=system-is-back-after-suspend.target
EOF

cat > "$sysd/self-poweroff.service" <<'EOF'
[Unit]
Description=Actual self-poweroff after suspend
After=suspend.target 
Before=system-is-back-after-suspend.target
RefuseManualStart=true

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl --no-block poweroff
# Uncomment the following line while commenting out the above line for testing.
#ExecStart=/bin/echo poweroff
# Note the echoed string goes to systemd journal log.
# Do a `systemctl daemon-reload` after modifying this file.
EOF

cat > "$sysd/schedule-self-poweroff.service" <<'EOF'
[Unit]
Description=Schedulation of self-poweroff after some time spent in suspend state
Before=systemd-suspend.service
Requisite=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
EnvironmentFile=/etc/self-poweroff.conf
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'printf -- %%s\\\\n "[Timer]" "Persistent=yes" "OnCalendar=$(date -d "now + ${MY_SUSPEND_TIMEOUT}" "+%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%M:%%S")" "AccuracySec=1s" "WakeSystem=yes" >| /run/systemd/system/self-poweroff.timer'
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl start self-poweroff.timer
# On systemd 237 onwards (Fedora 28 onwards) you may uncomment the line below while commenting out the above ExecStart and ExecStartPre lines
#ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'systemd-run --on-calendar="$(date -d "now + ${MY_SUSPEND_TIMEOUT}" "+%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%M:%%S")" --timer-property=AccuracySec=1s --timer-property=WakeSystem=yes --timer-property=Persistent=yes --unit=self-poweroff.service'
# Do a `systemctl daemon-reload` after modifying this file.

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
EOF

cat > "$sysd/system-is-back-after-suspend.target" <<'EOF'
[Unit]
Description=Synchronization point for self-poweroff after suspend
DefaultDependencies=no
After=suspend.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes
EOF

cat > /etc/self-poweroff.conf <<'EOF'
MY_SUSPEND_TIMEOUT=12 hours
EOF

systemctl enable schedule-self-poweroff.service cancel-self-poweroff.service
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Once the script has been run to install the Units, you can alter the timeout in the dedicated `/etc/self-poweroff.conf` file, which is also created by the script. There you set the `MY_SUSPEND_TIMEOUT` variable to whatever amount of time you wish, and you can express time in `hours` and/or minutes (`mins`) and/or seconds (`secs`) as per `date -d` command's date-parsing abilities.

Comment: Thank you so much, this script works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the full answer but might help you on your search is to edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and add the following lines.

```
IdleAction=poweroff
IdleActionSec=720min
```

This would poweroff poweroff the system after 12 hours of "idle" time. But I am not sure if the session is reported as idle if it is suspended.